# Scraped HTML is not written at the beginning of text file

Tags: html

Currently, I'm scraping the HTML code of a page, and writing it to a text file.

My problem is, why must there be empty spaces or empty lines at the beginning? The HTML codes written to the txt file do not seem to start at the beginning of the text file.  This means that the '<' is not located at the position 0 of the txt file.

After a few runs, my HTML is always written a few lines down inside the text file.

Can anyone tell me why?

Below is my code. I'm doing it under Visual C++ .

```
UINT32 LOG(wstring log, UINT32 flag)
{

    wfstream file (LOG_FILE, ios_base::app);
    file << log;         
    file.close();


return 1;
```

}

My problem is, the HTML code copied to my text file is always down a couple of lines, then will find the '<' tag. What I want is, the HTML's first '<' is written at the position 0 of my text file :)

Comment: @karikari what does the page you are scraping look like, and what does your code to scrape it look like?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have? What language is it in? What have you tried? Can you show us your output? This will help with debugging. Also, it's highly recommended that you mark some of your other questions as answered (assuming they have been), this will make other users more receptive to answering your questions.

Comment: @Pitss, I have tried to mark the answer given, but I can't. How to do that? :)

Comment: @ pitss, now I know. I have just registered. Im gonna mark my answered questions now. thanks to all stack overflow fans here. im learned a lot from this site :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code. I'm doing it under Visual C++ .

```
UINT32 LOG(wstring log, UINT32 flag)
{
if(flag == 0)
{
    wfstream file (LOG_FILE, ios_base::app);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file << log <<endl;         

        file.close();
        wcout << endl << log << endl;
        return 0;
     }
    else wcout << "\nUnable to open LOG file\n";
    return 1;

}
```

My problem is, the HTML code copied to my text file is always down a couple of lines, then will find the '<' tag. What I want is, the HTML's first  '<' is written at the position 0 of my text file   :)

Comment: Please update (edit) the question - do not add an 'answer' to expand on the question.

Comment: You open the file for 'append' (`ios_base::app`), so new material is added at the end of the file.  Also, your code snippet is incomplete; there is a close brace `}` missing and probably a return.